# Loop through CSV file and create new csv file with while read?

Tags: bash, text, csv, pattern-matching

I have

```
while read $field1 $field2 $field3 $field4
do
  $trimmed=$field2 | sed 's/ *$//g'
  echo "$trimmed","$field3" >> new.csv
done < "$FEEDS"/"$DLFILE"
```

Now the problem is with `read` I can't make it split fields csv style, can I? See the input csv format below.

I need to get columns 3 and 4 out, stripping the padding from col 2, and I don't need the quotes.

Csv format with col numbers:
12         24(")25(,)26(")/27(Field2values)   42(")/43(,)/44(Field3 decimal values)
"Field1_constant_value","Field2values            ",Field3,Field4

Field1 is constant and irrelevant. Data is quoted, goes from 2-23 inside the quotes.
Field2 fixed with from cols 27-41 inside quotes, with the data at the left and padded by spaces on the right.
Field3 is a decimal number with 1,2, or 3 digits before the decimal and 2 after, no padding. Starts at col 74.
Field4 is a date and I don't much care about it right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use read; all you've got to do is reset the environment variable `IFS` -- Internal Field Separator --, so that it won't split lines by its current value (default to whitespace), but by your own delimiter.

Considering an input file "a.csv", with the given contents:

> 1,2,3,4
>
> 2,3,4,5
>
> 6,3,2,1

You can do this:

```
IFS=','
while read f1 f2 f3 f4; do
    echo "fields[$f1 $f2 $f3 $f4]"
done < a.csv
```

And the output is:

> fields[1 2 3 4]
>
> fields[2 3 4 5]
>
> fields[6 3 2 1]

Comment: `while IFS=, read f1 f2 f3 f4; do ...` will avoid to set `IFS` for the whole script.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of good starting points for you are here: http://backreference.org/2010/04/17/csv-parsing-with-awk/